# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in milliseconds in h2

Tags: mysql, timestamp, h2

The question [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624284/current-timestamp-in-milliseconds/) discussed how to "get milliseconds out of a timestamp in `MySql` or `PostgreSql`". But the methods in the answers don't work because H2 doesn't support MySQL methods like `conv`.

I want to use a variant of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the `defaultValueComputed` of my schema file.

How can I get the exact milliseconds of a timestamp in `H2`? I want it be a `long`. I also want the milliseconds returned to be in [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Here it is in my schema file:

```
<column name="create_time" type="long" defaultValueComputed="?"
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

I have this `DAO` object:

```
public interface MyDao extends Transactional<MyDao> {
    @SqlUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO my_table "(id, create_time)" +
        "VALUES (:id, :create_time)"
    void insert(@BindBean MyObject myObject);
}
```

I looked at the "Time and Date Functions" section of http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html and couldn't find anything that could do this though maybe `PARSEDATETIME` somehow could work.

EDIT: Maybe an alias is possible. See groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/kziTTTNlB9o:

> I'm porting an application to H2 that was initially written for MySQL 
>   (the queries contain some MySQL-specific syntax).  Probably the most 
>   challenging part of getting the queries running on H2 has been the use 
>   of the MySQL date functions like DATE(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), and 
>   FROM_UNIXTIME().  The good news is: because H2 supports creating 
>   aliases for these, I was able to write a very small Java class that 
>   implements these MySQL functions for H2, and once I aliased them into 
>   place, H2 runs just about all of our queries without modification.

Comment: A good example of aliasing at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293598/how-to-write-a-function-in-the-h2-database-without-using-java.

Comment: And https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/Developing-with-the-H2-Database.

Comment: And another alias reference http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old question but anyone like me, can be search answer for this question. We can get current time by millisecond with `h2` `DATEDIFF()` function.

Fisrtly we pass current_timestamp and first date value and return type `SECOND` as a parameters like :
`DATEDIFF('SECOND', DATE '1970-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) * 1000` the returned result is current_time's millisecond for us.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to be accurate - there was a small diff between the result and the actual Unix timestamp.

Comment: could you provide code sample ? This logic did simple thing, actually. maybe you are trying to find second instead of millisecond.

Comment: so the difference when using your answer is that I get the timestamp in my local time zone (GMT+3 in my case), so it's not the same as the Unix time stamp (in millions). in my answer, I get the result in UTC.

Comment: as for code sample - `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select DATEDIFF('SECOND', DATE '1970-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) * 1000", Long.class)`

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the other answer here and it wasn't accurate - there was a small diff between the result and the actual Unix timestamp.

This, however, seems to work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (EPOCH from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) * 1000
```

It seems like in the other answer I get the timestamp in my local time zone (GMT+3 in my case), so it's not the same as the Unix timestamp (in milliseconds). in my answer, I get the result in UTC.