# Equivalent of UNIX_TIMESTAMP function for H2 DB?

Tags: mysql, h2, unix-timestamp

Does anyone know any proper substitute of MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_val)` for H2, such that applying that function on a JDBC timestamp returns a unix epoch from 00:00:00 01 Jan 1970?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CURRENT\_TIMESTAMP in milliseconds in h2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720739/current-timestamp-in-milliseconds-in-h2)

Answer (score 3):

```
DATEDIFF('SECOND', DATE '1970-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

as answered here: [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in milliseconds in h2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720739/current-timestamp-in-milliseconds-in-h2)

or here: https://gitlab.com/romain.rinie/h2database/issues/211

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to be accurate - there was a small diff between the result and the actual Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the other answer and the result wasn't accurate. In the other answer I get the timestamp in my local time zone (GMT+3 in my case), so it's not the same as the Unix timestamp (in milliseconds). In my answer, I get the result in UTC.

This would give you the correct current UNIX epoch:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (EPOCH from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've edited my answer to provide more context.