# Set a datetime column with a SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I using a MySQL server (5.5.27 - Community Server). I have a table with this definition:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_messages (
  `msg_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `msg_text` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`);
```

I write a trigger that, when I do an insert, the server sets the msg_id column with the current time including microseconds with this format "yyyymmddhhnnssuuuuuu". "u" is for microseconds.

I created a trigger:

```
create trigger tbl_messages_trigger
before insert on tbl_messages 
for each row

BEGIN
    SET NEW.msg_id = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s%f'); 
END;$$
```

But the msg_id column only gets values like this: 20130302144818**000000**, with microseconds in zero. ¿Is it possible capture the microseconds?

TIA,

Comment: It seems that with MySQL version 5.5 it's impossible, and I need 5.6.4 version...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979558/mysql-now-function-with-high-precision

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code provided I guess that you are trying to use microsecond to minimize probability of getting same msg_id for different rows.

Also, `msg_id` is the primary key, which should not present any object-specific data but only be unique. There is a good link about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

The best way to deal with primary keys in MySql is AUTO_INCREMENT column attribute. If you need insert time for messages, you may provide column for it:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_messages 
(
   `msg_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `msg_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `msg_text` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`)
);
```

Comment: That's what I looking for! With bigint, I need 58 billions of years, at 1000 new records per second to finishing it. Thanks!