# How to create Mysql unix_timestamp with millisecond

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php function using mysql query UNIX_TIMESTAMP() to create a unique transaction number, but I found that if the function loop in same time, it will generate the same transaction number for Case 1, using Case 2 is not a good way for huge loop.

1.I am using transaction number is for sorting same transaction date in table list.

2.My transaction table is using UUID as PK, because data cross DB.

**Desire answer is like below and unique.**

```
TransNo = 1397533879.20290
```

PHP Version 5.3

Mysql Version 5.5

E.g. Function Loop 3 times

**Case 1 :**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() as TransNo;

Output : 
1397533879
1397533879
1397533879
```

**Case 2 :**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() as TransNo, SLEEP(1);

Output :
1397533879
1397533880
1397533881
```

Comment: Why not use microtime in php?

http://us2.php.net/microtime

Comment: Ohya, thank @Joshua Bixler, I forgot php have this functions. But any way, did the mysql able to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979558/mysql-now-function-with-high-precision

Have to jump up version 5.6 to use it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Desire answer is like below and unique.*
>
> *`TransNo = 1397533879.20290`*

If you call `current_timestamp` or `now` functions with a precision for `microseconds` part, then they return a `timestamp` that includes current micro seconds of time. Please note that Maximum precision allowed is for `6` digits only.

See Documentation on  [***`Fractional Seconds in Time Values`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)

**Example 1**:

```
select 
    @ts:=current_timestamp( 3 ) cts_with_milli_seconds
  , unix_timestamp( @ts ) uts_with_ts_milli_seconds;
```

**Result 1**:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| cts_with_milli_seconds  | uts_with_ts_milli_seconds |
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2014-04-15 10:22:17.764 |         1397537537.764000 |
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
```

**Example 2**:

```
select 
    @nw:=now( 6 ) now_with_milli_seconds
  , unix_timestamp( @nw ) uts_with_nw_milli_seconds;
```

**Result 2**:

```
+----------------------------+---------------------------+
| now_with_milli_seconds     | uts_with_nw_milli_seconds |
+----------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2014-04-15 10:22:17.789248 |         1397537537.789248 |
+----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

**Side note**:
If still microseconds part too matches, then you can append `RAND()` to your values.

Usage of `RAND()` will not guarantee in sorting order. Hence, unless you need just a *unique* output, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks @Ravinder, I am using php microtime() provide by Joshua Bixler, it result as 1397537683.3391, 1397537683.3429, 1397537683.3456, it can solve my sorting problem, if using RAND() cannot guarantee in order insert.

Comment: `RAND()` suggestion was in case of micro part matching. And yes, on usage, sorting may fail. Otherwise my answer is as helpful as what is in referred posting.